# Passing int[] to method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arguments

I'm having trouble passing an int array to a method right now. They're in the same class, and if I switch the method argument to an int, and then use an int, everything works fine. I'm trying to pass an int[] like this:

`setBoardBulk({1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3});`

But doing this I get a:

`illegal start of experession`
`not a statement`
`';' expected`

for every element I pass. In this case I have 3 of each because I'm trying to pass 3 arrays. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only on declarations of arrays can you simply say `{1, 2}`.  With other array initialization expressions, you must explicitly include `new int[]` before the braces.  Try

```
setBoardBulk(new int[] {1, 2}, new int[] {1, 2}, new int[] {2, 3});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `setBoardBulk` takes 3 `int[]`s, you need to do as follows:

```
setBoardBulk(new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{2, 3});
```

The braces are valid at declaration, but need to be a full initializer in other places.